# Android bottomSheet высота, которая зависит от внешнего контента

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Есть вот такой экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внизу BottomSheet, у которого стоит
**app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"**

Но на разных разрешениях это выглядит не так как надо.

Как можно начальную высоту bottomSheet прикрепить к элементу "Заголовок" ?
Чтобы он был максимальной допустимой высоты, но не перекрывал заголовок.
Пример ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задавайте высоту программно. Вычислите допустимое значение, а после вызовите соответствующий метод `Bottom Sheet`.

Comment: Сейчас, собственно, так и делаю. Приходится начальную высоту ставить в 0 и программно ждать пока прогрузиться весь макет через OnGlobalLayoutListener, а затем уже просто из полной высоты вычитаю занятую. 

Я думал, что может есть какие то более легкие варианты.

Comment: Как вариант, можно попробовать использовать `Guideline`, но не уверен, что этот компонент подойдёт для решения вашей задачи. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline